# R - Loss labels when I subset a data frame after using read_sav from haven package

Tags: r, subset, r-haven

I use the `read_sav` function from `haven` package to import an SPSS file. Therefore I have column names and associate labels (class labelled).

I lost the labels when I subset the data frame with `subset`. I can use a workaround with indexing `data[i]` but is this behavior a bug or not ?

Here is a simple example.

```
DataForExample <- structure(list(q0001_0001 = structure(c(2, NA, 5, 4, NA), label = "être plus rapide", class = "labelled", labels = structure(c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5), .Names = c("non, pas du tout", "non, pas vraiment", 
"oui, un peu", "oui, tout à fait", "je ne sais pas"))), q0001_0002 = structure(c(NA, 
3, NA, 4, 2), label = "être plus fiable", class = "labelled", labels = structure(c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5), .Names = c("non, pas du tout", "non, pas vraiment", 
"oui, un peu", "oui, tout à fait", "je ne sais pas")))), .Names = c("q0001_0001", 
"q0001_0002"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

View(DataForExample) # OK
Toto <- subset(DataForExample, select = q0001_0001)
View(Toto) # NOK : the labels disappeared
Toto2 <- DataForExample[1]
View(Toto2) # OK
```

Thanks

Comment: `DataForExample["q0001_0001"]` - you can subset with names as well.

Comment: Thanks, but the main question remains.

Comment: My point is that subsetting as I suggest does not lose the labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same answer as with your previous question about sorting. You need to load package with support for subsetting operations for class `labelled`. It is better to load it after the `haven`. There are at least two packages with such support: `Hmisc` and `expss`. No additional actions are needed, just `library(expss)` or `library(Hmisc)`.

Comment: I wonder if I am doing something wrong. I was having the same subsetting resulting in lost label problems. After reading your answer, I loaded the Hmisc package. I then ran the same subset command, but still lost labels. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: @evt Try to run your code in clean session after restarting R. And `Hmisc` should be last loaded package.